# Python: how to get changes from (main)array in class-function

Tags: python, class

I would like to manipulate many parts of an array in a class-function.
I will return these parts as one array. It has the same structure as a part of the orginal array.
I know, I can not update the original array from within the class-function as it is not 'global'.

If I update the original array in 'main' with this returned partial array, I can access the new values in main, but not in class.
In class function the values are the old ones.

But it seems to work, if I only change one value, not a whole structure part of the original array.

Similar problem :
If I expand the array "SENSOR_config_array" in main, these will not 'arrive' in class-function

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8

from collections import defaultdict
import test_class as sensors
import copy

SENSOR_config_array=defaultdict(dict)
SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]=defaultdict(dict)
SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]["actualVal"]=3
SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]["maxVal"]=10


A10_sensors_class = sensors.deal_with_sensorData(SENSOR_config_array)
print ("original SENSOR_config_array:")
print (SENSOR_config_array)
print()

ret=A10_sensors_class.make_DataString() ## return "maxVal" should change to 20
print ("1. ret :")
print (ret)                             ## OK
print()

SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]["maxVal"]=20 ## "maxVal" set to 20
ret=A10_sensors_class.make_DataString() ## return "maxVal" should =40
print ("2. ret :")
print (ret)                             ## OK
SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]=ret      ## "maxVal" set to (returned)40
print ("2. SENSOR_config_array:")
print (SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"])  ## 40 !!!  it seems to be updated!!!
print()


ret=A10_sensors_class.make_DataString() ## return "maxVal" should =80
print ("3. ret:")
print (ret)                             ## NO !!
print()

SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]["Val"]=90
ret=A10_sensors_class.make_DataString2()    ## return "maxVal" should =180
print ("4. ret:")
print (ret)                             ## NO !!
print()
```

test_class.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
from collections import defaultdict

class deal_with_sensorData:
    def __init__(self, config_data):
        self.SensorData=defaultdict(set)
        self.SensorData=config_data["Sensors"]
        ## config_data has e.g.
        ## config_data["Busses"]["type"]
        ## config_data["Sensors"]["actualVal"]
        ## config_data["Sensors"]["maxVal"]

    def make_DataString(self):
        temp=defaultdict(dict)
        temp["maxVal"]=self.SensorData["maxVal"]*2
        return temp

    def make_DataString2(self):
        temp=defaultdict(dict)
        temp["Val"]=self.SensorData["Val"]*2
        return temp
```

**Output:**

original SENSOR_config_array:

defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'Sensors': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'actualVal': 3, 'maxVal': 10})})

1. call :

defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'maxVal': 20})

2. call :

defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'maxVal': 40})

2. call ret:

defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'maxVal': 40})

3. call ret:

defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'maxVal': 40})

4. ERROR

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that initial link between `SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]` and `SensorData` attribute of `A10_sensors_class` object is lost as the code runs on.

When `A10_sensors_class` object is created:

```
A10_sensors_class = sensors.deal_with_sensorData(SENSOR_config_array)
```

i.e. when the object in initialized in `__init__()` method

```
def __init__(self, config_data):
    self.SensorData = defaultdict(set)
    self.SensorData = config_data["Sensors"]
```

`self.SensorData`(`A10_sensors_class.SensorData`) and `config_data["Sensors"]` (`SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]`) are the same `defaultdict` objects.

However, by this assignment:

```
SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"] = ret
```

you link different `defaultdict` object to `SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]`, thus breaking the initial link between `SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]` and `A10_sensors_class.SensorData`, so changes in `SENSOR_config_array["Sensors"]` do not influence any longer the attribute `SensorData` of `A10_sensors_class` object. It becomes obvious if you check id of objects.

That is why change of `maxVal` in 3rd retry will not work.
And that is why calling method `make_DataString2()` generates error in `temp["Val"] = self.SensorData["Val"] * 2`. You try to multiply value that does not exist yet.

To avoid the situation you may return values, not dicts in methods `make_DataString()` and `make_DataString2()` and instead of assigning the whole dict assign just particular value.

Comment: Thank you.
Something like this was in my mind. The only explanation for me.
Is there a chance to return a dict and insert/replace a whole branch in original dict?
To return one value alone is no opportunity.